# Android, Check if socket can send a message?

Tags: android, sockets

In my app I have a `Socket` like this:

```
Socket socket = new Socket();
socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(ip, port), 5000);
outputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
inputStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
```

I write to this `socket` like this:

```
outputStream.write((message).getBytes());
```

And read from it like this:

```
while (true) {
        try {
            String message = inputStream.readLine();
            if (message != null) {
               //do sth here
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();        
        }
}
```

Now the problem is sometimes Internet connection is so slow, in a way that connection stays alive (socket stays connected) but cannot send any messages. In such conditions it seems like the `OutputStream` holds the messages until it is able to deliver them to server. All I want is know when the socket is in this state?

I can ask the above question in this way too: How can I know if the written message is delivered to server?

Note that checking whether device is connected to Internet or not doesn't help because the device is really connected but probably experiencing a poor connection.

Comment: whenever you message is acknowledged by server get something in return to know that your message was delivered

Comment: How to do that? @AkshayKatariya

Comment: @Jayden You have to do it explicitly in your comunication protocol.  When you send a message, the receiver will have to send a new message back in acknowledgement.

Comment: The real problem here is that you are reading lines but you aren't writing lines. Add a line terminator to the message bytes. And you must break out of the loop if `readKine()` returns null.

Answer (score -1):

> All I want is know when the socket is in this state?

It gets in that state when TCP acks from the server are not received by the client so those packets can be removed from the client's outgoing buffer.  As long as there is room in the buffer, a send will not block the caller.  But once the buffer fills up, subsequent sends block the caller until the buffer clears up.

The only way I know to detect this condition is to use the socket's [`getChannel()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#getChannel()) method to access its underlying [`SocketChannel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SocketChannel.html), and then [`register()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/spi/AbstractSelectableChannel.html#register(java.nio.channels.Selector,%20int,%20java.lang.Object)) that with a [`Selector`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Selector.html) that you can then monitor/query using its [`select()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Selector.html#select(long)) method to know if the socket is writable (has room in its outgoing buffer).

But, that will only be able to tell you if the socket can accept at least 1 byte for sending without blocking the caller.  It will NOT tell you if a given message can be accepted *completely* for sending, as the buffer could fill up before the end of the message is reached, in which case the send will block until the buffer frees up room for the *whole* message.

But, it would let you monitor the health of the socket connection, and if you find that sends are getting blocked too much due to slow/missing acks, you might have to just close the socket and reconnect.

> How can I know if the written message is delivered to server?

The only way is to have the server send back its own message after receiving the client's message.

Comment: Sorry Remy but the technique you have decribed does not work. You cannot put a channel derived from a `Socket` into non-blocking mode.

Comment: @EJP: Where did I suggest putting the socket channel into non-blocking mode?  I didn't.  `Selector.select()` has an optional `timeout` parameter.

Comment: @EJP: nevermind, I see what you mean: "*A channel must be placed into non-blocking mode before being registered with a selector*". So, you are saying one would have to use their own `SocketChannel` directly without obtaining one from a `Socket` in order to use non-blocking mode?